# Migrating from google+ sign-in to new google sign-in

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-plus, google-signin

I'm trying to migrate my web application sign-in from Google+ API since its deprecated and gonna get shut down by March. I created new  credentials(clientId,clientSecret) in Google API console. The OAuth scope is "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" and I got the access token. Which API should I use to get the user_info with the access token? I'm getting confused by the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you can try use Firebase like identity provider.
Look into this docs https://firebase.google.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of good choices.

- One of the [userinfo](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtaininguserprofileinformation) endpoints. The most recent endpoint is available in the discovery document at https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration under the `userinfo_endpoint` key.
- The [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/)'s [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) endpoint to get the "people/me" resource name. This gives you some flexibility about what fields you get. Depending on the fields you want, it might have a URL such as

  `https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=names,emailAddresses`